# Function to return percent frequency of string across multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
    tim       beth      stephanie
0   present   present   absent
1   absent    present   absent
2   present   present   absent
3   None      absent    present
4   None      present   None
```

I want to calculate the percent of `absent` and `present` for each row. To do so, I wrote a function:

```
def percentage(columns, percent): 
    for col  in df.columns:
        percent = (100 * df[col].value_counts(normalize = True))
        print(percent)
        return percent
```

I was hoping for a result like this:

```
absent     33.333333
present    66.666667
Name: tim, dtype: float64

absent     20.0
present    80.0
Name: beth, dtype: float64

absent     75.0
present    25.0
Name: beth, dtype: float64
```

However, the function I wrote does nothing. I know this should be easy, but I'm still confused. Any tips or help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to print? If so, you could just do :

```
def percentage(columns): 
    for col in columns:
        print(100 * df[col].value_counts(normalize = True))

percentage(df.columns)
```